# AdMob - Get Notify when isReady property changes

Tags: ios, swift, admob, key-value-observing

I trying implement *Rewarded Ad* - [Rewarded Ads New APIs (Beta)](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-ads). Video is load and `isReady` property is changing to `true` in a couple of seconds.

I have a button on which user press and *Rewarded Video* appear

This is function which is fire when user press on button

```
func presentRewardAd(from viewController: UIViewController) {
    if rewardedAd.isReady {
        rewardedAd.present(fromRootViewController: viewController, delegate: self)
    }
}
```

**The problem is**

I want to hide button until video `isReady == true`, and when it's ready show button. So i want to get notify when `rewardedAd.isReady` is changing.

**What i try so far:**

```
class CustomRewardAd: GADRewardedAd {

    private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override init(adUnitID: String) {
        super.init(adUnitID: adUnitID)

        observation = observe(\.isReady, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
            print("isReady changed from: \(change.oldValue!), updated to: \(change.newValue!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Also i tried this [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) but same result.

But `changeHandler` never gets called. Am i doing something wrong?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, not ideal but it's works! Maybe this is can help someone in future.

When new rewarded request finishes, `isReady` property is set to `true` or `false` depends what response is.

```
private func createAndLoadRewardedAd() -> GADRewardedAd {
    let rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
    rewardedAd.load(GADRequest()) { [weak self] error in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.videoIsReady?(rewardedAd.isReady) // already set
    }
    return rewardedAd
}
```

**You are welcome!**